# Wordpress widget update instances for items that need tags

Tags: php, widget, adsense, wordpress

Recently I realized I do not utilize widgets in WordPress enough when developing sidebars in themes so I have spent the last couple of days researching how to develop them properly.  After reviewing a lot of tutorials I have found a number of them on custom building widgets to be outdated.  I did see where I should use the construct:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
    // Base ID of your widget
    'foobar_widget', 
    // Widget name will appear in UI
    __('Give them foo Widget', 'foobar_widget_domain'), 
    // Widget description
    array( 'description' => __( 'Development widget for testing', 'foobar_widget_domain' ), ) 
    );
}
```

The [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) is very minimal when it comes to custom widgets.  After browsing SO's tags [wordpress-widget](/questions/tagged/wordpress-widget) and [widget](/questions/tagged/widget) I didn't see a solution when calling an update for the widget if a textarea is needing tags.  A large number of people show calling the title instance as:

```
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
```

In my function `form()` I am needing a textarea that will take user input code, like a copied Google Adsense ad.  The following works but I am unsure if there is a better approach to accepting input from the form:

```
// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance['foo1'] = $new_instance['foo1'];
    return $instance;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to return the `$instance` when you need tags without using PHP's `strip_tags()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use following awesome code snippet to register a custom widget which takes any HTML

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'register_widget("clean_markup_widget");'));
class Clean_Markup_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::WP_Widget('clean_markup_widget', 'ASR Custom Text Widget', array('description'=>'Simple widget for well-formatted markup &amp; text'));
    }
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract($args);
        $markup = $instance['markup'];
        //echo $before_widget;
        if ($markup) echo $markup;
        //echo $after_widget;
    }
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['markup'] = $new_instance['markup'];
        return $instance;
    }
    function form($instance) {
        if ($instance) $markup = esc_attr($instance['markup']);
        else $markup = __('&lt;p&gt;Clean, well-formatted markup.&lt;/p&gt;', 'markup_widget'); ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('markup'); ?>"><?php _e('Markup/text'); ?></label><br />
            <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('markup'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('markup'); ?>" type="text" rows="16" cols="20" value="<?php echo $markup; ?>"><?php echo $markup; ?></textarea>
        </p>
<?php }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to return the `$instance` when you need tags without using PHP's `strip_tags()` ?

Yes! WordPress has many ways to validate and sanitize user data.

For your case [`wp_kses_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post) should work very well.

It's description is: *Sanitize content for allowed HTML tags for post content.*

It uses a default list of allowed tags, which you can find in [`wp-includes/kses.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L56).

If you wish to only allow specific tags the safest way to do that is by using `wp_kses()` instead of `wp_kses_post()`.

The difference being that `wp_kses()` requires a second parameter for `$allowed_html` instead of using the `$allowedposttags` global variable.

There are ways to filter or override the `$allowedposttags` global variable but are probably not the best idea in this case since they will effect other HTML, like post content, in addition to your widget.

You update function with `wp_kses_post()` would look like this:

```
// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance['foo1'] = wp_kses_post( $new_instance['foo1'] );
    return $instance;
}
```